# How to reuse the code in situations where input param is a reference ?

Tags: java, linked-list

This code would convert a linkedlist like : 1-> 2 -> 3 -> 4, into 1->3-2->4 (ie odd on left and even on right), except the problem caused by `oddEvenSplitter` function. This code will modify references by value. How to reuse the code in such situations where input is a reference ?

```
public void oddEvenSplitter (Node head, Node current, Node temp) {
    if (head == null) {
        head = temp;
        current = temp;
    } else {
        current.next = temp;
        current = temp;
    }
}

public void oddFirst( ) {
    if (first == null) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }

    Node temp = first;
    Node oddhead = null;
    Node odd = null;
    Node evenhead = null;
    Node even = null;

    while (temp != null) {

        if (temp.element % 2 == 0) {
            oddEvenSplitter(evenhead, even, temp);
        } else {
            oddEvenSplitter(oddhead, odd, temp);
        }
    }

    if (oddhead != null) {
        odd.next = evenhead;
        first = oddhead;
    }

}
```

Comment: If it's not a homework, I'd written special Comparator and used default `sort` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java does not have pass by reference. It always passes values. When you pass for example `oddHead` variable to `oddEvenSplitter()` method, what really happens is that a copy of `oddHead` variable is passed and from that point `head` and `oddHead` variables will be two separate variables, pointing on same object in the heap. So if you assign new value to `head` variable inside your method, the other one (`oddHead`) will remain unchanged. This is true for all other passed parameters as well.

As a solution you could create another object (like a DTO) and put all needed references inside it and pass it to your method. Then whenever you change those references, you will be able to get them in caller method.